# CSS file isn't being refreshed

Tags: html, css, filezilla

So I've got my own website, and I just made some adjustments to one HTML file and the global CSS stlye sheet file. On my computer, it looks as I want it. On my website however, the old settings are still adapted - the new HTML file is correctly displayed, but the new CSS settings aren't being adapted. I've tried the following:

- Cleared my browser's cache
- Checked if my zoom was 100%
- Deleted my CSS file from the server (strangely, my site looked exactly the same as if the CSS file was still on the server)
- Refresh my maps in FileZilla before replacing the new CSS file with the old file

What's happening here?

Comment: Try forced refresh (ctrl/shift+F5) as suggested by Adil. Make sure you have copied the correct file to correct place. Make sure you are actually looking at correct file. I have made all these mistakes. :-)

Comment: Thanks Edu! Ofcourse I refreshed that page many times, but by using Shift + F5, the page was displayed correctly :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append a parameter after the css link to have the browser force refresh.

Each time you need a file refresed add ?

```
"style.css?1"
"style.css?2"
"style.css?3"
```

Also as Edu mentioned above, please make sure you're copying and linking the correct files.

Comment: I've run into this kind of issue on dreamhost with pagespeed enabled. Using a param on the end of the CSS does the trick. It considers it a new url, and refetches it.